# How to replace NULL with the previous value?

Tags: sql, sqlite, interpolation, sparse-data

My table:

| field5 | field19 |
| --- | --- |
| Dr | 1 |
| NULL | 2 |
| NULL | 3 |
| Td | 4 |
| Td | 5 |
| NULL | 6 |

SQL query should give following result:

| field5 | field19 |
| --- | --- |
| Dr | 1 |
| Dr | 2 |
| Dr | 3 |
| Td | 4 |
| Td | 5 |
| Td | 6 |

Comment: This could definitely benefit from more explanation of what it is you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window function would help :

```
select *,  
      max(field5) over (order by field19)
from table t;
```

You can also use *correlated* subquery :

```
select t.*,
       (select t1.field5 
        from table t1 
        where t1.field19 <= t.field19 and t1.field5 is not null
        order by t1.field19 desc 
        limit 1
       )
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, which finds the previous **non** `null` value for `field5`(if it exists):

```
select 
coalesce(t.field5, (
  select tt.field5 from tablename tt where tt.field19 = (
    select max(tablename.field19) from tablename where tablename.field19 < t.field19 and tablename.field5 is not null)
  )
) as field5, 
t.field19 
from tablename t
```

**Schema (SQLite v3.26)**

```
CREATE TABLE tablename ( field5 TEXT, field19   INTEGER ); 
insert into tablename (field5, field19) values 
('Dr1', 1), 
(null, 2), (null, 3), 
('Td', 4), 
('Td', 5), (null, 6), (null, 7),('Dr1', 8),(null, 9),('Td', 10),(null, 11),(null, 12);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
select * from tablename;

| field5 | field19 |
| ------ | ------- |
| Dr1    | 1       |
|        | 2       |
|        | 3       |
| Td     | 4       |
| Td     | 5       |
|        | 6       |
|        | 7       |
| Dr1    | 8       |
|        | 9       |
| Td     | 10      |
|        | 11      |
|        | 12      |
```

---

**Query #2**

```
select 
coalesce(t.field5, (
  select tt.field5 from tablename tt where tt.field19 = (
    select max(tablename.field19) from tablename where tablename.field19 < t.field19 and tablename.field5 is not null)
  )
) as field5, 
t.field19 
from tablename t;

| field5 | field19 |
| ------ | ------- |
| Dr1    | 1       |
| Dr1    | 2       |
| Dr1    | 3       |
| Td     | 4       |
| Td     | 5       |
| Td     | 6       |
| Td     | 7       |
| Dr1    | 8       |
| Dr1    | 9       |
| Td     | 10      |
| Td     | 11      |
| Td     | 12      |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t662wkYUahMo5ig2aJVZEP/2)

Comment: Have results like this null 2, null 3, null 4

Comment: @NuttyBunny Click the link of the demo and check that it is working. If this is not working with your data then you did not post the right sample data or you did not explain what you want correctly.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `tablename` (
 `field5` TEXT,
 `field19` INTEGER
);

insert into tablename (field5, field19) values
('Dr1', 1), (null, 2), (null, 3), ('Td', 4), ('Td', 5), (null, 6); (null, 7);('Dr1', 8);(null, 9);('Td', 10);(null, 11);(null, 12);

Comment: @NuttyBunny So you did not post the right sample data.